# Why my Django server not work suddenly?

Tags: python, django, linux

I am woking on Ubuntu 12, python2.6 and Django1.2.x which is my test server.
And I run a Django project on my test server using below command:

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

The server can work for most time(I let it run on 7X24 for other teammate to access it), but sometime it would suddenly not work:

- Browser shows me that "server not available" when I try to access it.
  And of course, the test server cannot get any request from my frontend, and no error throws on server side.

All will back to OK once I using  my django project and run it again.

now I have 2 question:

1. Why does this issue happend?
2. How can I develop a shell script to detect this situation?

Comment: Ubuntu 12.4 has Python 2.7, later versions are Python 3.x. Did you install Python 2.6?

Comment: _where_ do you run the manage.py command? Inside `screen`, init script or `nohup`?

Comment: As commented below, django's dev server should not be used for production. Try runnning manage.py runserver with `--noreload`, it might make it more robust (give `--nothreading` a try too).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, it looks like you're trying to use Django development for production purposes. There may be a lot of explanations, like apparmor config, or limitation of single-threaded server, but the problem doesn't worth investigating. Just install Apache2, or Nginx, or uwsgi, and that's it, you have good and stable server without shell watchdogs and other kludges. It would probably take about the same time as posting to SO

Comment: Thanks!! I think you are right. I should not waste too much time on this worthless investigating.